# An example of the use of the Point class?

Tags: java, point

I'm trying to use `Point(double x, double y), getX(), getY()` to create a point and return it with `toString()`. I can't find an example of how to do this anywhere.

```
public class Point {

    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("(" + x + "," + y + ")"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Huh? What *exactly* has you stumped? What *can* you do, and what trips you up? Please clarify this for us, including showing us more good and even bad code.

Comment: I'm to create a class that holds the x and y coordinate of a point on the cartesian plane and return it in the form "(X,Y)".

Comment: public class Point {
 
    private final double x;
    private final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
     this.x = 1;
     this.y = 1;
    }
    
 
    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }
 
    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
 
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("(" + x + "," + y + ")"); 
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your original question and supply this information there where we can read it. There's an edit button just below the question tags. Then show us how you try to use your Point class, and what problems your code attempts are havng.

Comment: Why are you setting `x` and `y` to 1 in your constructor?  That seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: OK, so what is your question exactly?  What doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to do this instead:

```
public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Then...

```
System.out.println(new Point(5.0, 5.0).toString());
```

I don't know why you're setting the this.x and this.y values to 1 in your constructor. You should be setting them to the provided values of x and y.

You also don't need the outer set of parentheses in the `toString()` method. `return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";` will work fine.

Answer (score 3):

I think you look for that:

```
public class Point {
private double x;
private double y;

public Point(double x, double y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
}public String toString(){
    return "("+ this.x+","+this.y+")";
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    Point point= new Point(3,2);
            System.out.println(point.tostring());
    }
}
```

to had getX() getY() just have to create them.

Answer (score 0):

Same could be done with just the data class in Kotlin, with like this:

```
data class Point(val x: Double, val y: Double)
```

You can access all the methods above without creating it. Something like this:

```kotlin
val point = Point(3.0,4.0)
val result = point.toString()
```